# SQLAlchemy: Need help to translate this complex raw query to ORM (subqueries, window functions)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Here is a postgres query that I would like to translate to sqlalchemy ORM:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *, 
      date_trunc(
        'hour',
        time_obs + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
      ) AS usedTimestamp,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY icao,
        date_trunc(
          'hour',
          time_obs + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
        )
      ORDER BY
        LEAST(
          EXTRACT(
            MINUTE
            FROM
              time_obs
          ),
          60 - EXTRACT(
            MINUTE
            FROM
              time_obs
          )
        )
      ) AS seqnum
    FROM
      metar_current
    WHERE
      icao = 'DGAA'
  ) AS dt
WHERE
  seqnum = 1
AND LEAST(
  ` EXTRACT(
    MINUTE
    FROM
      time_obs
  ),
  60 - EXTRACT(
    MINUTE
    FROM
      time_obs
  )
) <= 15
ORDER BY
  time_obs ASC
```

If it is not possible (or to difficult) to translate this to sqlalchemy ORM, then is there some way that I could query this as raw sql, but reference the resulting data using column names?

Comment: To the "could [I] query this as raw sql": [`Query.from_statement()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_statement) allows you to run queries against SQL statements returning ORM entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but I was able to figure it out myself - though I am not sure that this is the optimal way to go about it.

```
seqnum = func.row_number().over(
    partition_by=[Metar.icao,
                  func.date_trunc('hour', Metar.time_obs + text("INTERVAL '15' MINUTE"))
                  ],
    order_by=func.least(func.extract("MINUTE", Metar.time_obs),
                        60 - func.extract("MINUTE", Metar.time_obs))).label('seqnum')

dt = session.query(Metar,
                   func.date_trunc('hour', Metar.time_obs + text("INTERVAL '15' MINUTE")).label('usedTimestamp'),
                   seqnum
                   ).filter(Metar.icao == icao).subquery('dt')

q = session.query(Metar, dt.c.usedTimestamp).filter(dt.c.seqnum == 1,
                                                    dt.c.icao == Metar.icao,
                                                    dt.c.time_obs == Metar.time_obs,
                                                    func.least(func.extract("MINUTE", Metar.time_obs),
                                                               60 - func.extract("MINUTE", Metar.time_obs)) < 15) \
    .order_by(Metar.time_obs).all()
```

The reason that I joined `Metar` to `dt` instead of just selecting from `dt` as in the original raw query was so that I could access the resulting data by `Metar`'s class properties.